# Disable Button at a Process

Tags: xcode, button, process

how can i disable all Buttons at a Process. At my Project a Button download a File an when the download beginn i would disable all Buttons it is finish should be all Buttons work.

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://db.tt/x8imQ0C"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:@"/var/root/The best of S.A.F.rar"];
    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressView];
    [request startAsynchronous];

}
```

Comment: giving some code snippets (showing what you have done, and how you've attempted to solve the problem) would be a good start if you intend on getting some useful tips/answers here.

Comment: Sry i forgott it i have edite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an easy way is create IBOutletCollection for all of your buttons then you can disable them like this :

```
[myButtons makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setUserInteractionEnabled:) withObject:nil];
```

for enabling again :

```
[myButtons makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setUserInteractionEnabled:)];
```